# how to get data into an array after post using axios in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am creating album using reactjs. I'm using `loopback-storage-connector` for storing images.

this is my code for uploading image

```
fileUploadCarImg =()=>{
    for (let index = 0; index < this.state.file.length; index++) {
        const element = this.state.file[index];
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('image2',element,element.name )
        axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/attachmentBanks/Car_Image/upload',fd , {
            onUploadProgress : ProgressEvent => {
                console.log('Upload Progress: ' + Math.round(ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total *100) + '%')
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.result.files.image2[0].name)
        });

    }

}
```

I want to store those image names into `loopback-mysql-connector`. so my idea is storing each and every image name (`res.data.result.files.image2[0].name`) into an array.

while uploading image `console.log(this.state.file)` print

```
Array(8) [ File, File, File, File, File, File, File, File ]

(8) […]
​
0: File { name: "IMG_20150905_072534.jpg", lastModified: 1442772056000, size: 241381, … }
​
1: File { name: "IMG_20151110_115108.jpg", lastModified: 1447206282000, size: 2749010, … }
​
2: File { name: "IMG_20151110_115124.jpg", lastModified: 1447206242000, size: 2797533, … }
​
3: File { name: "IMG_20151110_120625.jpg", lastModified: 1447205916000, size: 725661, … }
​
4: File { name: "IMG_20151110_120642.jpg", lastModified: 1447206122000, size: 687308, … }
​
5: File { name: "IMG_20151110_120704.jpg", lastModified: 1447205958000, size: 3364141, … }
​
6: File { name: "IMG_20151110_121043.jpg", lastModified: 1447205998000, size: 2921138, … }
​
7: File { name: "IMG_20151110_121050.jpg", lastModified: 1447206044000, size: 3867974, … }
​
length: 8
​
<prototype>: [
```

I just need to store name of the image.
Anyone please give any hint to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, consider to use `await`

```
let data = [];
for (let index = 0; index < this.state.file.length; index++) {
    const element = this.state.file[index];
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image2',element,element.name )

    try {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/attachmentBanks/Car_Image/upload',fd , {
            onUploadProgress : ProgressEvent => {
                console.log('Upload Progress: ' + Math.round(ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total *100) + '%')
            }
        });

        data.push(res.data.result.files.image2[0].name);

    } catch(error) {
        //your handler
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
const names = res.data.result.files.map((file) => file.image2[0].name);
```

The array is quite hard to decipher, but with minor adjustments it should work.

Comment: thank you sir, but shall I write your code under he then part in axios?

Comment: Yes, just put it where you logged the result

Comment: sir but, my console.log(names) code not display anything

Comment: Could you provide the schema for the object you receive? It might be easier to help you this way

Comment: Please edit your question and add that information there. Questions in this site should contain all the information available.

Comment: sir . when I run console.log('Upload Progress: ' + Math.round(ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total *100) + '%') only printed.

Comment: Sir please check it now